# Show softkey pannel over a button in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a login application in android, in that i have got a image, edit box & a login button. When user taps on a edit box keyboard pops up, but this will cover the login button, i want the login button to be placed above the softkey pannel. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's one option that lets you effect that:  android:windowSoftInputMode.  It can be set to pan or resize.  Try setting it to resize, that will resize your application to be above the keyboard-  unless the keyboard is lieing about its size and using a transparent overlay technique.  If it is, you don't really have an alternative, its doing something you don't have controls for.

Comment: See my response; Android only tries to prevent the soft keyboard from obscuring the view that currently has input focus (the EditText). If you use `adjustPan`, it will pan the window to keep the EditText on screen. If you use `adjustResize`, it will resize your window and scroll enough to keep the EditText on screen.

Comment: I know that, I wrote Swype.  That's why I said to use resize, he wants the login button above the keyboard.  Still, that will only work on some keyboards-  one modern trend in keyboard design, especially on tablets, is to lie about your size and use transparency to lie on top of the app.  This breaks the whole mode selection, since to do it you lie about your height and claim its 0 when computing your insets, causing it to pan 0 pixels (or resize to the same size).

Comment: Can we scroll down the entire scroll view to the bottom as soon as softkeyboard is opened?

Answer (score 2):

Android only tries to prevent the soft keyboard from obscuring the view that currently has input focus, which would be your `EditText`. (This is true regardless which setting you use for `windowSoftInputMode`.) I suppose you could design your screen layout such that the login button is in the upper half of the screen and so will not be obscured when the keyboard appears.

Instead of trying to keep your button on screen, why not add some extra functionality to the keyboard? Make the enter key say "Go" or something and just submit their info when the user hits it. This way they don't have to lower the keyboard and press the login button, they can just hit the enter key on the keyboard. See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action) for info.

Comment: Can we scroll down the entire scroll view to the bottom as soon as  softkeyboard is opened?, is tat option works?

Comment: I'm afraid not-  unless it was added recently, there's no way to be informed when the soft keyboard opens.  The only control you have is setting it to pan or resize (pan is the default).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view to resize in response to the keyboard by adding "adjustResize" to the imeOptions (from memory) of your login activity in the ApplicationManifest then adjust your layout to match the new window size (see android:windowSoftInputMode in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html ). I don't really recommend this, you will find you barely have enough room for the edit box on some smaller devices. Perhaps a better solution would be to have the action button on the soft keyboard do the same action as your login button, so when the user finishes entering username/password, they can login without needing to hide the keyboard...
See "Specifying Keyboard Actions" here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: Oh, I see a number of other posters have also said this. Moving along. ;-)